# How to remove string from a string,With replace metod(regex)

Tags: java, regex, string

Need to convert the input String

```
{"emp":{"ID":1212,"num":145},"type":"s"}
```

to the following format

```
{'ID':'1212', 'num': 145, 'type':'s'},
```

Removing `{"emp:"` and `}` after `num:145`

Comment: Which lang you're running?

Comment: Java Program which reads from file,Now the string should be reduced to the above format,I have many data in the same format

Comment: Instead of regex, why not use a Json parser instead?

Comment: @Rakesh if you're dealing with a valid JSON format - use a JSON parser to read the object and create a new object derived from it - in the required format. Regex doesn't seem fit for this task doesn't!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all the datas are in the same format like above then you may use this regex.

```
string.replaceAll("\"emp\":\\{([^}]*)\\}", "$1");
```

- `"emp"` matches the `"emp"` string.
- `\\{` Matches a single curly brace.
- `([^}]*)` negated char class which matches any char but not of `}` brace, zero or more times. `()` capturing group present around the negated char class helps to capture that particular chars.
- `\\}` matches a closing curly brace.
- So this will replace all the matched chars with the chars present inside the first capturing group.

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/eP4nF7/1)

Comment: For learning purposes, shouldn't you explain what the pattern of the replaceAll does?